# Save users data to CSV file

Tags: ruby, class, csv

I am new in ruby so please forgive the noobishness.

I  have a class "User" which have methods create and show all users need to save "users" data in CSV file

This is what i tried to do

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :email

  def initialize(name:, age:, email:)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @email = email
  end

  def create
    @users = [@name, @age, @email]
  end

  def self.all
    ObjectSpace.each_object(self).map(&:create)
  end

  def self.save_to_csv
    CSV.open(users.csv, "w") do |csv|
    @users.each { |i| csv.puts "#{i.name}, #{i.age}, #{i.email}" }
  end
 end
end
```

When i call

```
User.all
```

it returns me arrays in array of my users, but when call

```
User.all.save_to_csv
```

it shows me error

```
<main>': undefined method `save_to_csv' for [["user1"], ["user2"], etc]
```

Please, help how it's should be properly doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.all` returns an array of all the instancies of User and its attributes, it's an array, and you've not defined `save_to_csv` for Array objects.

You could try `User.save_to_csv`, that's the class method to open the CSV file and write the user's info on it, but there's other problem, there's no `@users` variable in your class, so it'll take the value of `nil`, and there's not `each` method for `nil:NilClass`.

So I think you could use the `all` method, to access all users, and then to iterate.

After this you can push to the CSV file's line the array with the user's data:

```
def self.save_to_csv
  CSV.open('users.csv', 'w') do |csv|
    all.each { |user| csv << user }
  end
end
```

Note `csv.puts` won't work.

Comment: I think i should change method "all", but don't understand how to do it properly

Comment: In the `self.save_to_csv` method `all.each` makes reference to the `self.all` method applying `each`, so instead calling the method as `User.all.save_to_csv`, you can do `User.save_to_csv` without chaining methods.